# Slow HTTP requests on Android when setting android:targetSdkVersion > 10

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm having a strange problem. Without setting `android:targetSdkVersion` my http request takes around 1.. 2 seconds to be completed, setting `android:targetSdkVersion="16"`, for example, the requests take around 20...30 seconds!

I logged when the request starts and I noticed that when I start the `Activity`, the system keeps in idle until make the request.

All requests are running in `AsyncTask`.

Here is the code:

```
BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, HTTP_POST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, HTTP_POST_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
...
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I tested and it happens on android:targetSdkVersion >= 13

Comment: Try HTTPURLConnection instead of HTTPClient.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not use `DefaultHttpClient` in Android. Please try to use `AndroidHttpClient`. It contains several changes and improvements for mobile device, so maybe it will help in you case.

Comment: appears some optimizations setting android:targetSdkVersion="16" are causing some "lock"

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?